# View Creation failed

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a view in sql server using below query:-

```
create view vkb1 as 
select dept, AVG(salary), count(eid)
from emp_sal
group by dept
```

But it is giving me below error:-

```
Msg 4511, Level 16, State 1, Procedure vkb1, Line 17
Create View or Function failed because no column name was specified for column 2.
```

Please help me in this.I am new to the sql.

Comment: What part of the error message do you not understand?

Comment: you need to provide alias names to the columns that are being Averaged and counted.
for example: select dept, Avg(salary) as avg_salary

Answer (score 1):

You have to name the two columns without any name:

```
create view vkb1 (dept, avg_salary, eid_count) as 
select dept, AVG(salary), count(eid)
from emp_sal
group by dept
```

Alternative solution:

```
create view vkb1 as
select dept, AVG(salary) as avg_salary, count(eid) as eid_count
from emp_sal
group by dept
```